# Blazor Server with Azure Service Bus Messaging

Tags: azure, blazor-server-side, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am far from an expert in this topic, so I would need your advice.

Whar are the possibilities of listening to a Azure Service Bus Queue in a Blazor Server web application? When I have looked through more or less all examples on this topic, the messages are usually sent by a web application but consumed by a console app.

What i have done so far is that i have implement the creation of the messages (sender functionality) into an existing rest api. That is straight forward i guess, and it seems to work just fine.

How to handle the web site is another topic, but i want a sign in and out functionality of the listener. We can see it as a go LIVE feature. To manage this, i implemented the processor logic instead on the receiver logic, so that i can sign in and out of the message event.

Can this work? Or shall i do something different instead?

It somehow works, but there are errors that interfere and i am not skilled enough to say if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [SignalR chat app sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) for guidance. You can replace the SignalR code with your ServiceBus client logic and there should be no issue.

The sample also contains buttons to start/stop the chat similar to your requirement for login/logout.

Comment: Agree. I think I got it to run and as you mention, the workflow is pretty similar between SignalR and Service Bus.